# Sorting pairs by first coordinate

Tags: r

I have the following vectors:

```
X<-c(140,140,130,109,124,114,65,162,150,0)
Y<-c(30.65,6.45,17.74,11.29,3.23,3.23,3.23,8.06,14.52,1.61)
```

What I would like to do is assign each entry in X to the corresponding entry in Y, and then order them by X. For example, if I had

```
J<-c(10,40,20)
K<-c(9,9,2)
```

I would like it to give me

```
Jo = (10,20,40)
Ko = (9,2,9)
```

How do I do this in R? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `order()` function:

```
X <- c(140,140,130,109,124,114,65,162,150,0)
Y <- c(30.65,6.45,17.74,11.29,3.23,3.23,3.23,8.06,14.52,1.61)
ord <- order(X)
(X2 <- X[ord])
##  [1]   0  65 109 114 124 130 140 140 150 162
(Y2 <- Y[ord])
##  [1]  1.61  3.23 11.29  3.23  3.23 17.74 30.65  6.45 14.52  8.06
```

(Don't really need to save `ord` if you re-order Y first; could use `Y2 <- Y[order(X)]; X2 <- sort(X)` instead.)